# R: Subsetting on increasing value to max excluding the decreasing

Tags: r, subset

I have a number of trials where one variable increases to a max of interest then decreases back to a starting point.  How would I go about just retaining the observations with the increasing values to max.  Thanks.

For example

```
Trial A B C
    1 2 4 1
    1 4 3 2
    1 3 7 3
    1 3 3 2
    1 4 1 1
    2 4 1 1
    2 6 2 2
    2 3 1 3
    2 1 1 2
    2 7 3 1
    ...
```

So we would check max on C and retain as follows,

```
Trial A B C
    1 2 4 1
    1 4 3 2
    1 3 7 3
    2 4 1 1
    2 6 2 2
    2 3 1 3
    ...
```

Ultimately I'll have a low cut off value as well as varying perhaps what I mean by max but essentially the above is the aim.

Comment: You could start with a reproducible example and desired output illustration

Comment: Yeah, I should have...but thought this might be one of those very simple examples. I'll see about editing.

Comment: Try `df[c(TRUE,diff(df$C)>=0),]`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, yes, I think you are right.

Comment: @nicola I guess this won't work if the beginning if the first incident of the second group is smaller than the last one in the first. Not sure if this possible in the real data though

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, that's my same thought. I actually don't have time now to fix this problem; if you or other want to use my comment as a base for an answer, feel free of course.

Comment: Maybe `df[ave(df$C,df$Trial,FUN=function(x) c(TRUE,diff(x)>0))==1,]`? Ok, now I really need to leave and can't test with other sets of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the most efficient solution, but here is an attempt using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[1:which.max(C)], by = Trial]
#    Trial A B C
# 1:     1 2 4 1
# 2:     1 4 3 2
# 3:     1 3 7 3
# 4:     2 4 1 1
# 5:     2 6 2 2
# 6:     2 3 1 3
```

Or for some efficiency gain

```
indx <- setDT(df)[, .I[1:which.max(C)], by = Trial]
df[indx$V1]
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine on your data set, unless you can make your example more reproducible I can't help you.

Comment: My mistake...I actually typed **SD[1:which.max(df$C]...".  Works. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%group_by(Trial)%>%slice(1:max(C))
```